# How to get Unity's 4.6 UI images to layer over each other perfectly?

Tags: unity, gui

I've been noticing that if I have two images, lets say squares. I have  A as the parent of triangle B. Triangle A and B both have their offsets at their anchors, which are on the 4 corners of it's "box".

Triangle A should be behind triangle B, since it renders from top to bottom in the hierarchy (the last item being on top). However as I re-size my screen, sometimes triangle  A will poke out from behind triangle B. Even if they both are using the same image, and have the exact same dimensions.

Whats causing this, and how do I fix it?

Additionally, I noticed that while the anchors and offsets can be finely adjusted, the image is not. You have to adjust by certain interval sizes and the image will just snap to that new size rather than adjusting finely as you change the offset or anchors.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I had pixel perfect enabled, without it enabled this solved the problem I was having.